# How does qt paint its widgets without using native code?

Tags: qt

I heard that qt(older versions, at least) do not use windows native API to draw its widgets. I want to know how is this possible ? how does it draw without calling functions from the native API ? is there a way through which creation of non-native widgets is possible ?if yes, then what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know where you heard that, but all drawing operations will at some point need to make platform API calls. Drawing anything on the screen would otherwise be impossible.

Unless by "painting" you mean the way Qt creates the image data for the widgets prior to drawing them on the screen. In that case, yes, Qt rasterizes on its own. It still gets some image data from the native API though, otherwise it wouldn't be able to produce widgets of the currently set theme.